# How to list folders in linux older than x days without listing their contents?

Tags: linux

I have below folder structure:-

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec  8 10:07 2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 10 04:29 3
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 10 04:55 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 11 04:55 5
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 12 06:25 6
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Jan 16 01:04 7
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Jan 16 05:03 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 200 200  496 Jan 16 07:57 a.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 200 200   40 Jan 16 07:57 a.xml.sha1
-rw-r--r--. 1 200 200   32 Jan 16 07:57 a.xml.md5
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Jan 16 07:57 9
```

All the above directories contain some files inside.

I need to list down only folders inside this directory that are older than 30 days omitting *.xml files in the output. Only folders should be listed

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

I tried running below command but I am getting the contents as well in output.

```
find . -type d -mtime +30 -exec ls {} \;
2  3  4  5  6 
2.prop 3.prop 4.prop 5.prop 6.prop
```

I also tried running below command but not getting any output.

```
find . -type d -mtime +30 -exec ls -l {} \; | grep '^d' | awk ‘{print $9}’
```

I also tried below command but not getting desired output.

```
find . -type d -mtime +30 -exec ls -ld {} \;
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec  8 10:07 ./2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 10 04:29 ./3
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 10 04:55 ./4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 11 04:55 ./5
drwxr-xr-x. 2 200 200 4096 Dec 12 06:25 ./6
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `-exec ls -ld {} \;` should do it. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank for the help. I have provided the output after appending your suggestion. It doesn't give me the desired output. I need only folder names in the output. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why are you exec-ing at all?  Just use `-print`:  `find . -type d -mtime +30 -print`.

Comment: what did you think would happen when you use the `-l` option to `ls`? remove `-l` and see what happens, but agree with WP, `-print` is probably the best way. (For future reference, `man ls` will help you with what options are available and what they do). Good luck.

Comment: This type of question has been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid an answer.

Answer (score -1):

To list all directories including subdirectories:

```
find . -type d -mtime +30
```

If you only want directories that are in the current directory (i.e. not subdirectories) use the `-maxdepth 1` flag

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30
```